# Windows Update randomly turning off - Virus/Rootkit?

Tags: windows-7, security, virus, anti-virus, uac

*I deleted my last question. It fixed itself*

Anyway after my computer fixed its slow performance problems it now will turn off Windows Update whenever it wants to. I figure this is some sort of virus or security flaw that is making it turn off, but I am very concerned because i have ran multiple virus/malware scans with 2 different scanners (Avast and Malwarebytes) and they have picked up nothing.

In Application in Event Viewer there are multiple cases of Software Protection stopping by an unknown user.

Most of security was logging on and off, besides some misspelled passwords.

And then in System: The Windows Update service entered the stopped state. Then a couple hours later i turned it back on. User is N/A.

What i am asking is how can i fix this? I am concerned about my security of this computer and files that are on it. I havent updated my computer lately, even though Windows Update says i should, but i am nervous to do so because i am afraid this virus/malware/rootkit could do more damage.

This trusty (but dusty) old computer of mine has always filled my needs and i would hate to have to get a new computer or erase my hard drive.

Thank you, and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the Software Protection and Windows Update services stop and restart themselves (as o others). They don't need to run all the time, so to save taking resources away from you and other processes they turn themselves off, and the system schedules their restart at whatever interval they ask for.

So your trusty old computer is trusty still! (But may appreciate a bit of a dust!)

Comment: although it is turning off quite frequently... still your answer?

Comment: @DallinWright - yep. Just looked at my Windows 10 log. Security turns itself off 3 times a day, after running some checks and rescheduling a start.

Comment: would this apply to Windows 7 too?

Comment: The service starting and stopping yes. The details of what it logs (that it's rescheduled itself etc) I don't know.